# Adding array values from nested json file to dictionary in Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary, swift4

I need to add nested array values from a json files to a dictionary in swift 4.

This is the json that I am loading:

```
{
"type": "Scripted",
"language": "English",
"genres": [
    "Drama",
    "Romance"
],
"status": "Ended",}
```

I am creating a struct dictionary that will contain the data from the json file but I am having issues adding the contents of "genres" in the dictionary. This is how I am initializing this:

```
struct Show{
let id: Int
let name: String
let type: String
let genres: Genres

enum SerializationError:Error{
    case missing(String)
    case invalid (String, Any)
}

init?(json:[String:Any]) throws{
    guard let id = json["id"] as? Int else {throw SerializationError.missing("id is missing")}
    guard let name = json["name"] as? String else {throw SerializationError.missing("name is missing")}
    guard let type = json["type"] as? String else {throw SerializationError.missing("type is missing")}
    guard let genresDict = json["genres"] as? [String: Any] else {throw SerializationError.missing("genres is missing")}
    guard let genres = Genres(dict: genresDict) else {return nil}

    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.type = type
}

struct Genres{
    let genres:String

    init?(dict: [String: Any]){
        guard let genres = dict[] as? String else { return nil }

        self.genres = genres
    }
}
```

}

I am not sure of how to define the path to the "genres" array in this bit guard **let genres = dict[] as? String else { return nil }**

How should I proceed from there?

Comment: `json["genres"] as? [String: Any]` => `json["genres"] as? [String]` It's an array of String, not a Dictionary. You can change the init too.

Comment: Thanks @Larme , it did the trick, just had to consider it as an array of Strings